# Group based trajectory modeling in R

Tags: r, statistics, longitudinal

I have a dataset consisting of 3 variables one ID, on variable Y, and time variable t.

It is in long form with each subject having several rows of registrations with the ordinal variable Y (1-5) and time of registration with the first registration being 0 and the rest in months since first registration. The time points are different for each subject.

I want to group the subjects based on similar Trajectories of Y over t.

I have tried the gbmt package but the results seem nonsensical. I am now trying the flexmix package but I cant figure out how to plot the Trajectories.

I am fairly new both in statistics, R and programming so any help is welcomed. I'm open to other packages if flexmix is not right for this.

This is a small data sample with same structure: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6528f6249eaf6cc2e488193c58aed84b20231208151530/e90fa7

This is the code for the small dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(flexmix)
library(ggplot2)

#fit model
fit <- flexmix(Y ~ t+I(t^2) | ID, data = data, k = 3)
summary(fit)
clusters(fit)

#add groups in dataset
data$group <- clusters(fit)

#add the change of Y
data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(change_Y = Y - first(Y))

# Calculate mean change in Y for each group at each time point
mean_change_data <- data %>%
  group_by(group, t) %>%
  summarise(mean_change_Y = mean(change_Y, na.rm = TRUE))

# Plot the mean change in Y for each group over t

 ggplot(mean_change_data, aes(x = t, y = mean_change_Y, group = group, color = as.factor(group))) +
  stat_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE, alpha = 0.2) + 
  labs(title = "Mean Change in Y Over Time",
       x = "t",
       y = "Mean Change in Y") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Group")
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image: This is the resulting plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexmix` is a regression package, and gbmt is for trajectory analysis. I am not about the speciality of these two packages, but usually you can do analysis using the most common packages.

**Edit:** I can see a couple of issues here. 1) you first fit the model with original 'data', but then you modified the data with baselining and averageing 'Y' (Why you need to do it?). This clearly makes the data no longer predictable by the existing model. 2) For plotting the model fitted with original data, try the code below (removed 'stat_smooth' as it does not relevant at all (it's another basic model).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=t,y=Y))+
geom_point()+   
geom_point(aes(col = as.factor(model@cluster))) +   
geom_abline(data = as.data.frame(t(parameters(model))), aes(intercept = `coef.(Intercept)`, slope = `coef.Time`, col = as.factor(seq_along(sigma)))   )
```

Still, you should first standardized your trajectories, meaning consistent intervals (define one, e.g., 1 s) between time t. You can use `complete()` from `dplyr` package to standardize time t and `na.approx()` from `zoo` package to interpolate coordinates Y for each group - 'ID'.

```
data %<>% group_by(ID)%>%
  dplyr::complete(t = seq(min(t), max(t), by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(Y = zoo::na.approx(Y))
```

Optionally, you can align all the trails by extending last coordinates of the shorter ones to the longest one. Then you may summative calculate common metrics, like overall length, duration, velocity and etc..

Your case seem not to necessitate Finite Mixture Models, you can do polynomial regressions using `glmer()` or `glm()` from `lme4` package, which is a much more popular package with rich support. Check this book for the method https://www.researchgate.net/publication/290152385_Growth_Curve_Analysis_and_Visualization_Using_R

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will look into those. I want to ask. I have implemented flexmix models as
fit <- flexmix(Y ~ t | ID, data = data, k = 3)
I've seen people use t + I(t^2) too so I tried that too, although I dont get why it's there.
Even though this model is not explicitly using t as time, but just as a continuous variable, can you tell me if the results from that can actually be used for grouping similar trajectories, considering that the subjects get grouped based on their change of Y over t? Note that the t here is not standartized.

Comment: For visualization I did 
data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(change_Y = Y- first(Y))

mean_change_data <- data %>%
  group_by(group, t) %>%
  summarise(mean_change_Y = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE))
and then plotted the mean cahnge of Y for the group per time point over time.
I end up with a 3 line plot with lines above 0 for group that have increasing trends etc.
Does this make sense to follow?

Comment: The problem with gbmt was that it required the exact same time points for all subjects which is almost impossible to have in my data, since I have about 11 million registrations of about 800.000 subjects with the time points being in time since first registration and the intervals being different for everyone.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that there is huge variability in the time points. Some subjects have hundreds of registrations while others have only e.g only 3. Could the standardization process handle this ?
Sorry for the storm of comments but I feel this is out of my league and trying to figure it out

Comment: @Tasosmav Let's answer your question 1. 't + I(t^2) ' is like the growth curve analysis by interacting time with factors 'I', which allows to produce predictions at every time point for different levels of factor 'I'. However,  't' alone does not make sense me. The typical formula is like `dv ~ t*iv+ t^2*iv` , in your case is 'ID' your iv?

Comment: @Tasosmav For comment 2, why don't you update sample data and plot in the question? It would be easier to understand.

Comment: @Tasosmav For question 3 &4. If some trials are too short or long. Obviously, you need to remove outliers, e.g., using 3MAD or or ther criteria. Then, standardization is to be carried out within each trial using it max and min time. Next, you can align all the trails by extending last coordinates of the shorter ones to the longest one.

Comment: I have updated the question you can check the code the plot and a similar dataset. Thank you so so much

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your help. The plan I have in mind now is
1) Remove outliers with too few observations.
2) Remove observations from outliers with too many observations.
3) Standardize time inervals for each ID
4) Interpolate the values for the new intervals
5) No extension to align points since the last registration is important. It could mean death of a subject or other event that impacts registration and we need a time to event on a following analysis.
6) Fit the model. I will try different things here and I will also try lme4.
7) Plot trajectories...

Comment: 8) Identify factors that impact group membership. (I will think more about how to do this, based on the nature of the trajectories. Perhaps if they are in an ordered fashion I could use ordinal regression with clusters as the outcome, but that's further down the path.
Again thank you very much!!

Comment: Just to clarify though, in the standardization process you use interval 1. I would like to use the median of the difference between all registrations. Is the end goal to have the exact same time points for every subject or just the same intervals between registrations for each subject? In the first case I can use the median of the difference for each subject, in the second I have to use the median of the difference of all subjects combined.

Comment: @Tasosmav Your plan sounds good to me. Note for observations, you certainly don't need to remove trials with too many observation (the more the merrier). You may consider use the range of time instead, removing trials that is too short or too long. For your last question, if you don't want to extend the end of earlier finished trials, then you will only get "same intervals between registration". Also, you can try with "the median of the difference", but it may not be guaranteed to be appropriate (sampling rate often needs to below 1s) if your difference are generally large.

Comment: I used your code data %<>% group_by(ID)%>%
  dplyr::complete(t = seq(min(t), max(t), by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(Y = zoo::na.approx(Y)) , with by = median of difference instead of 1. The result is a dataset that contains both the original and the interpolated registrations. I believe from this dataset i could only keep the standardized time points and remove the originals, so I end up with the exact same time points for every trial.  Then i round the interpolated values to the closest integer since the variable is ordinal.

Comment: I ended up using 
filled_data <- data_standardized %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Y_interpolated= ifelse(is.na(Y), round(na.approx(Y), 0), Y))
because idk why but the interpolation in the previous code did not work as expected. This one seems to work as i'd expect it to.

Comment: @Tasosmav Cool. As long as it works for you.

Comment: Do you think instead of identifying clusters and then doing regression with the groups as outcome, I could only identify one curve and use the lme4 package with glmer() to identify how each indepented variable impacts curve growth? This way instead of having e.g one rising and one lowering group and find factors that affect the group membership I immediatly get how each variable affects curve growth for the whole population. Am I thinking straight here?

Comment: @Tasosmav You can use `lmer()` instead of glmer(), since you don't need any transformation of dv - Y. However, if you treat 'ID' as a random effect, what is your iv? Vice versa.

Comment: I haven't thought about if my subjects will be random or fixed effects I need to reflect on that a bit. If I follow this approach I have several independent variables I could include both continuous and categorical. I suppose I can do a multivariate analysis, with lmer() right?

Comment: @Tasosmav Yeah. you can do multivariate analysis with lmer(). You certainly need to be clear about your ivs.